# How to inline images in Pages

Tags: mac, layout, iwork-pages, word-processing

I'm having problems trying to place images inside a Pages document. I simply cannot get the images to stay where they need to be whilst ensuring they move to the next page if they don't fit on the current.

The **Arrange** sidebar for my image looks like this:

[image]

But this is what happens when I try to place an image in a target location near the bottom of a page:

[image]

Is this a fundamental limitation of Pages, or is there some way to get image placement to behave sanely?

**UPDATE:** per Krams' suggestion, I tried dragging from the *top* of the image. Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the image still does not position correctly. To help get this answered, I have also created a repro Pages document that you can download [here](http://cl.ly/3C1e3g183r0M). This document allows you to experience exactly what I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object arrangement placement is set to align text "Above and below" your object/s.

Your grab position on the image (whilst moving) is determining your placement on the page prior (as the point in which the image becomes visible on that page). As Pages is unable to show the image at the lower section of that page at the point of where your mouse grab position is clear of bottom margin, it has to force the text "below" the image.

Grab the image at the top of the object and try again, you should have some room to move onto the previous page and leave some space for text to remain above.

That said, you won't be able to see your whole image as it is too large to physically place all those elements into the same physical space... it's a time-space-continuum issue or so I've heard.  :-p

Good luck.

Comment: All I want is for the image to be placed at the point indicated. If that requires pushing all text below to a new page, so be it. If it implies pushing the image itself to a new page as well, so be it. Are you saying Pages cannot do this? Apparently Microsoft Word has solved the space-time continuum issue...

Comment: Did you try what I said?  Grab the image more towards the top-of-the-image, then do the same drag move up to previous page. You will see that your mouse-pointer position on the image greatly influences how it is represented on the previous page. Instead of Pages having to present the top 3/4's of your image (as you had it), it might only have to display (initially) top 1/4 of the image (as you move to previous page). So, this then allows for some text above the image to remain. The image will be off (below) the page mostly (as it's too large), and the text displaced will move to next page.

Comment: _In terms of my answer, the credible/official source is by actually replicating your scenario in Pages, and doing as I indicated, and it worked.  :-)_

Comment: yes, of course I tried what you said - I should have pointed that out. It doesn't work much better. Will post an update to the question shortly.

Comment: please see my updates, including a repro Pages document to demonstrate exactly what I'm trying to fix

Comment: _I think I have it now... ;-)_  Change the Arrange window Text Wrap setting from "Above & Below" to "Inline with Text". This appears to do what you initially indicated, which is allow positioning between particular text lines, but also handle the paragraph neatly. In this case, it will take the whole section to the next page (it appears) due to the large image size (I assume). It should still move with text block when editing, but it appears to have built-in "widow/orphan" controls like MS Word (but perhaps not so adjustable?).

Comment: @Kent  When moving the image in "inline" mode, it seems to not be as visual as "Above & Below" mode. You need to look beyond your image and look closely for the roving cursor "I" in amongst your text. Thats where you're placing the anchor for the image (it seems, from my testing).

Comment: Now *that's* what I was after :) Not as intuitive as I would have expected, but totally works. Any centering the image just requires placing the cursor just before it and centering the text instead. Thanks for following through Kram!